# In bigquery, can you specify a language when using format_date - Localization in date functions

Tags: date, google-bigquery, localization

I can't find a way to format a date in `GCP bigquery` using a specific language:

```
select CONCAT(FORMAT_DATE("Semaine du %d %B au ", date_trunc(current_date(),ISOWEEK)),FORMAT_DATE("%d %B", date_trunc(DATE_ADD(current_date(),INTERVAL 7 DAY),WEEK)))
```

It renders `"Semaine du 17 May au 23 May"`, meaning `"week from XX to XX"` but in French.

I would like to be able to set the  month names in french but can't find how to set that explicitly in `FORMAT_DATE` function?
Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BigQuery doesn't provide you localization options for Date Functions.

The solution is to use a short function to replace common names, which are very limited from English to the language of your choice. The function can be reused.