# how to get name of the month Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I need to get name of the month on Bigquery but in different languages .
my code : select FORMAT_DATETIME("%B", DATETIME('2022-01-04'))
get it only in english.
thank you.

Comment: Answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67581755/in-bigquery-can-you-specify-a-language-when-using-format-date-localization-in

Answer (score 0):

There is no localization for date functions in BigQuery. You have a couple of options: write a function to replace the month names with the languages you'd like. Or, create a translation table with the English names and names you need, then join on that to display the desired language.